# Inteligent patterns matching with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision

I have 35 images like this one: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/pat-all-lines.png. All of them are octagons with four numbers within, and hand made lines connecting the numbers (similar to a graph). A pattern can have one line, or two... or six, so there are 2 pow 6 = 64 possible valid combinations.

I have to make a python script to count how many different (unique) combinations are. How can I do that?

Here are some constraints:
- Any different pattern from those 64 should NOT be accepted. Example: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/pat-wrong01.png and https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/pat-wrong02.png
- Lines can be longer, shorter and not very straight, like these ones: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/pat-shaked-lines.png

I thought that perhaps the right way to go is with artificial intelligence and some sort of training on accepted patterns, and that somehow a function could return the more like pattern and its matching score (i.e: from 1 to 100)

Any suggestion? Please keep in mind that I'm a total newbie to opencv.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You have to better define what is accepted and what is not, otherwise any technique you try will give bad results. For instance, after considering the "shaker lines" pattern, to me it seems like "pat-wrong02.png" is a perfectly valid pattern: it is connecting 1 to 2, 2 to 4, and 4 to 3. It just happens that the person that did it didn't bother to draw four individual somewhat straight curves.

Comment: that depends on how robust you want it to be, if a line can go out from one point, and go any distorted path and finally reach another point, no program can be that accurate. One way to handle this is to have a large set of both correct cases and wrong cases. Then you can pick any classifier, knn, svm etc. I think the raw feature would suffice if there are no extreme cases like I described.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I thought about creating a mask for acceptable area per segment (line) and then analyze if there is a line within that area and how straight or long is it. Like this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/area-pattern-a.png [b,c,d,e,f]. If is not a good approach then I think the only way to go is with neural networks. Which approach would you recommend? Thanks again!